Can time derivatives in an autonomous system of ODEs remain nonnegative given nonnegative off-diagonal partial derivatives?
I have an autonomous system of ODEs:
$$\frac{d\vec{x}}{dt}=\vec{f}(\vec{x}),$$
with a couple peculiarities. Namely, for each component function $f_i(\vec{x})$, we have that $\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}\ge 0$ for $j\neq i$, that is to say that other nodes generally increase a node's activity. Now the system doesn't blow up because $\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_i}$ becomes (or always is) strongly negative; you can assume that $\lim_{\vec{x}\to\infty}\vec{f}(\vec{x})<\vec{0}$. In most cases the $f_i$ are also Lipschitz, so we can assume solutions are unique.
The question now is, given we start at $\vec{x_0}$ with $f_i(\vec{x_0})\ge0$ for all $i$, can we show that $f_i(\vec{x}(t))$ remains greater than zero for all times for all $i$? The intuition is that a node’s activity can only decrease if its neighbors' activities decrease or its own activity causes it to decrease. Thus as long as no $f_i(\vec{x_0})$ drop below zero, none will drop below zero. As you might be able to tell by this last sentence, I can't come up with a convincing argument, let alone a proof (neither in the affirmative or a counterexample).
What I have tried so far is a proof by contradiction: let $s<\infty$ be the infimum of times such that afterwards there is an $i$ with $f_i(\vec{x_0})<0$. Then, it is relatively straightforward to show that all time derivatives are nonnegative at time $s$. Now, let $k$ be a node such that $\dot{x}_k(t)<0$ for all $t\in(s,s+\varepsilon)$ for some $\varepsilon>0$, so $k$ is a node that starts decreasing immediately after $s$. Then I regard the total derivative:
$$\frac{df_k(\vec{x})}{dt}=\frac{\partial f_k}{\partial x_k}\frac{dx_k}{dt}+\sum_{j\neq k}\frac{\partial f_k}{\partial x_j}\frac{dx_j}{dt}.$$
After splitting into some cases ($f_k=0,f_k>0$), most of which easy and leading to contradiction, I get stuck on the case that both $f_k(\vec{x})=\frac{df_k(\vec{x})}{dt}=0$. Now you would like to conclude that because both derivatives are zero, and all other time derivatives are greater than or equal to zero, you cannot have that $f_k$ turns negative right after time $s$. But you could imagine if somehow two nodes $x_i$ started decreasing at the same time, they would also cause each other to decrease. And so I get stuck on trying to derive a contradiction in general based on what "caused" a node's activity to decrease.
I've tried to use a Gronwall-inequality type argument, to bound $x_k$ or $dx_k/dt$ from below, but I couldn't get this to work. I've also tried to use a uniqueness argument, but I can't think of anything that works.
It feels like I'm missing some basic element of differential equations and their solutions, but I can't see it. Any theorems, papers, articles, hints, ideas(, and of course solutions) would be amazing, and thank you in advance for your time.
Thanks for reading,
Alex

Have a look here (in particular Theorem~4): http://www.math.us.edu.pl/smdk/herzle.pdf

@Gerd Incredible! This solves my problem in one blow as far as I can tell. If you want to add this as an answer, I'll accept it. Thank you for your answer and introducing me to this theory

Glad I could help. I think for a link a comment is ok.
